# How can I assign a calculated percentage as a DIV's margin using JQuery (or JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'm building a page that uses Jquery path animations. The animated DIVs are positioned by query on page load and then they animate. When the animation completes, I want the DIVs to be positioned by css using percentage margins, so they will retain their relative end position when the screen is resized. My problem seems to be that I can't assign a percentage margin using .css() even though I'm currently passing it x% as a string! I'm new to programming so I could use all the help (and experienced eyes) I can get. This is also my first question so please bear with me if I posted this incorrectly. The script and css files I'm using are large (not to mention JQuery 2.x) so I pasted snippets of the code below:

HTML:

```
<div>
  <div class = "frame">
  <div class = "photo">
</div>

<div class = "orbit one"></div>
<div class = "orbit two"></div>
<div class = "orbit three"></div>
<div class = "orbit four"></div>
<!--<div class = "orbit five"></div>
<div class = "orbit six"></div>-->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.photo {
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #aef;
  position: relative;
  height: 35%; /*380px*/
  width: 35%; /*380px*/
  margin: 8.33% 0% 0% 33.5%;     /*50px 0px 0px 268px*/
}

.orbit {
  z-index: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: Red;
  height: 10%;/*15%*/
  width: 10%; /*15%*/
  position: relative;
}
```

JS:

```
fix: function fix(button, position) {
    var left = position.left.toString();
    var top = position.top.toString();
    console.log(top);
    console.log('left: ' + left.concat('%'));
    button.css({'margin-left': left + '%'});                    
    button.css({'margin-top': top + '%'});        
    console.log(top);
    console.log('fix received: ' + button);
    console.log('and set top margin to: ' + button.css('margin-top'));
    console.log('and left margin to: ' + button.css('margin-left'));
}
```

Comment: can you put your code is jsfiddle and post your jsfiddle here.? that would be more understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you apply margin as a percentage, the browser calculates it relative to the parent elements **width**. This means that the parent div needs to have an explicit width, for the margin to have any effect.
Check out this [article](http://mattsnider.com/css-using-percent-for-margin-and-padding/) for more in depth information.